# Syntax error when using set_index function

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to use the set_index function to create a MultiIndex, I get a syntax error. All of my previous code runs perfectly.

Code:

```
df.set_index = (["BillDocumentNo","ProductKeyID"], drop=False)
```

Error Message:

> File "", line 1
>       df.set_index = (["BillDocumentNo","ProductKeyID"], drop=False)
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any solutions?

Comment: If you can't figure out a problem this trivial, I'm curious to know how your previous code works at all. set_index() is a function, you're supposed to call it. Not assign something to it. Look at the documentation for the function and do a little reading on how it is supposed to be used: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in your code
There should not be any "=" between `df.set_index` and `(["BillDocumentNo","ProductKeyID"], drop=False)`

Try the code below :

```
df.set_index(["BillDocumentNo","ProductKeyID"], drop=False)
```